# Spring boot Jpa is not working with Spring batch and spring integration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I am working with spring batch. I needed to add some jpa repositories. So previously i was using JDBCTemplate which was working fine.

But when I started working with JPA, the spring boot application could not find the repos. Which were there.

```
@Autowired
ClassLevelConfigRepo clcr;
```

I checked these things as the best practices.

1. Added `@EnableJpaRepositories` in springBoot application class.
2. Added `@Repostiories` to the repository interfaces.
3. extended the interfaces with `JpaRepository<Account, String>`
4. Added `@Entity` to the entity classes and defined the `@Table and @ Column` annotations properly.

But I am still getting below error.

`Field clcr in com.cloudtask.batchconfig.util.LhmUtility required a bean of type 'com.cloudtask.batchconfig.repo.ClassLevelConfigRepo' that could not be found.`

I tried checking all the dependencies in pom.xml it was as per recommended. And I have all the tables defined properly in data base.

## I was expecting the application to return the Autowired clcr object propely.

Edit 1 : spring boot application annotations

````
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.cloudtask"})
@EnableAsync
@IntegrationComponentScan({"com.cloudtask"})
@EnableIntegrationManagement(defaultLoggingEnabled = "true")
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EntityScan
public class imclassApplication ```
````

Comment: 1. Don't as that will generally do more harm then good in a Spring Boot application. 2. Doesn't add anything but code, `@Repository` on a Spring Data based repository is useless. 3. You need at least one of the Spring Data types to extend, so `JpaRepository` should do. 4. At least the `@Entity` is needed to be able to detect it. To add make sure you are using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` as a starter and that your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class is in the `com.cloudtask.batchconfig` package.

Comment: Looks like you have checked the basic points. working with integration and batch you may have specified the package for ```@ComponentScan```.... Could you please share the annotations defined in your spring boot application class?

Comment: thanks @M.Deinum . I have a proper @Entity, @Repository interface which extends JpaRepository<ClassLevelConfigRepo, String>. and my springboot application class is in ```com.cloudtask.batchconfig.application``` package.

Comment: @Santrupta thanks. I have added the annotation details in the question.

Comment: And there is your problem. As I stated make sure your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class is in the `com.cloudtask.batchconfig` **not** a subpackage (and if you do you can remove all those annotations exception `@SpringBootApplication`, `@EnableAsync`, `EnableIntegrationManagement`. As I also stated (which you ignored) the `@Repository` is useless on Spring Data based repositories.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum Yes I noticed the spring boot applicaiton class is not in batchConfig. I could not change that as it will affect other developers.

Comment: Why would it affect other developers? It will only make life a lot easier. The fact that you need to bolt on more and more annotations to make it work is a sign that you are doing things the wrong way. Generally things should work out-of-the-box, if they don't it mostly is something in your setup (excluding auto-config classes or not adhering to the proposed standard packaging).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you work with Spring Data Jpa with those basic points you should also keep track of below points.

1. you have added `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` in your pom.xml
2. you have added the `entity` and `repo` package below one level of the application package.
3. If you the package is at same level you should specify the exact package details in the annotation. in your case it should be like :

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.cloudtask.batchconfig.repo")
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.cloudtask.batchconfig.entity"})
```

Happy programming!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Let me try and com back.

Comment: yes. It is working. Adding the base package details it solved the issue. Thanks a lot